# upgraded to PHP7 on Windows: php_soap.dll causing crashes / frequent 500 errors

Tags: php, windows, soap

I have two servers, a test server running Windows 7... and a prod server running Windows Server 2008.  (Yeah, it's unfortunate that they're different OS's.)

For months now, they've been running on PHP 5.4.1.4.

I decided to upgrade them to PHP 7.    Everything went completely fine with the test box.   But of course, it doesn't get much traffic.

On the prod / Windows Server 2008 box, it seems like, web apps would run for a minute or two and then show "500 error".   I could refresh and sometimes they'd work again, sometime it'd take a few minutes.

Nothing is/was getting written to the NEW PHP error log (even though IIS's PHP Manager section showed that we were pointed to the correct INI and the correct log file).

The webserver failed request logs simply indicated that FastCGI was failing because of too many 500 errors.

I checked Event Viewer and I would see application crashes that would point to php_soap.dll.

Now, that file is THERE and it's the same size as the one I have over in non-prod.

Still, I thought perhaps it was because my scripts were getting 500 errors for a valid reason.  So I investigated one of them.  Confirmed that it was an exact match to a working one on the test box.  Refreshed it...and it worked fine.  Refreshed some more, 500 errors.

So, finally, I went into IIS Manager -> PHP Manager and disabled the SOAP extension.

I then STOPPED seeing the massive number of failed requests and I stopped seeing the 500 errors... for everything except the one script I have that makes SOAP calls.

I tried copying the dll from the test box over to the prod box.  Enabled the extension again in PHP.   The issue returned.    So, I've pointed us back to the 5.4.1.4 config for now.

Any ideas on how I might figure out why this dll is causing issues and/or how to fix it?

Thanks!

-= Dave =-

Comment: Copying a DLL over from different environments may not be the best idea since it may be compiled for one system but fail on another. Also, you'll need to recompile it for PHP 7 and not use the same one as you used in PHP 5 (if you already haven't). If this is not the issue then I guess you could raise this with the PHP people as a possible compatibility issue.

Comment: Both the test and prod servers... when I did the php upgrade installation... used the Web Platform Installer and both used the x64 PHP 7 installations.   So, when I said I was copying over the DLL, I'm thinking it should have been the exact same file.

Comment: Usually it works, but if you want to completely eliminate to possibility of bad DLLs for a specific system you'd need to compile from source targeting the specific PHP distro and architecture.

Comment: Well, I figured out how to point only certain directories / applications to PHP7, while leaving everything else back on 5.4.14.   So, running a simple script that makes one SOAP request... if I run it from command line, it works.  If I run it via web browser, it errors.  Event Viewer notes the app crash and points to that php_soap.dll again.   Failed req log says FastCgiModule notification 128, notes the 500 error....and says "The extended attributes are inconsistent.(0xff)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out a fix.  I'm not sure why I'm only having to do this on the prod server, though:    The directories that my scripts that make SOAP calls are in were set to allow both Anonymous Authentication and Windows Authentication. When I was manually testing things in my browser, it would accept me and run the script as Anonymous.

I suddenly realized a theory:  my erroring script was being called by remote desktop gadgets...so it was probably defaulting too to executing anonymously.  But I have another script with SOAP in it that's run by Scheduled Task (as a specific user).  I had NOT seen that erroring!

So, I turned off Anonymous Authentication on the directory I was testing and reran my script from my browser.  Sure, I had to log in, but it then worked!  I checked my version of the Desktop Gadget that calls a SOAP script in that same directory...and it was now working too!

I think the key reason why I did not see this on the test machine is that we really don't have any Desktop Gadgets pointed to those proxy SOAP scripts over there.  That, plus I had THOUGHT that my script that runs by Scheduled Task was failing on the prod machine, as I know I saw it throw 500 errors within the first few minutes after I activated PHP7 the first time....and that same Scheduled Task/script DOES run over on the test box.

Thanks!

Comment: It turns out that my scripot that runs by Scheduled Task WAS failing as well... I just wasn't seeing a bunch of Failed Request Log files getting generated from it.  I couldn't figure out how to fix it, since it's the one SOAP-calling script I have that's actually triggered by a DOS batch file / PHP CLI.    (And that would explain why I wasn't seeing FASTCGI log those failed requests. It wasn't using FASTCGI.)

I ended up rewriting that script so that it uses CURL now instead of the SOAP module.

Comment: My guess at root cause is:   something about SOAP and its authorization requirements must have changed between  PHP versions 5.4.14 and 7.... though I don't understand why I didn't see any logging about some sort of authorization failure anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old now but I had a similar problem and it turns out that the cached WDSL files are not binary compatible between versions of PHP.

By default in php.ini the SOAP module has caching enabled. In order to avoid a crash you'll either need to clear the current WDSL cache or change the cache location for the new PHP install.

Hope that helps...